# A Way to move an instance to another class in javascript

Tags: javascript, function, class, object, instance

I was actually practicing creating classes and instances of them using the `new` keyword and this came to my mind.

Suppose I have a superclass called `Customers` and I have two subclasses which are `newCustomers` and `specialCustomers`.

Suppose that I have a new customer called bob ==> `var bob = new newCustomer();`

and I have a special customer called smith ==>>

```
var smith = new specialCustomer();
```

How can I write a method that when assigned to bob, it moves him from being a newCustomer instance to a specialCustomer instance?

like for example, what code should I write to make this work:

```
bob.moveToSpecial() //moves bob from being instance of newCust to specialCust
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An object is not an instance of a class, an object has a prototype based upon the constructor called.

What you can do (although it may lead to side-effects) is changing the prototype of that object:

```
bob.__proto__ = specialCust.prototype;
```

Read about the warnings when doing this here: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto

A better way is to create a new object and move all properties from bob there:

```
newBob = new specialCust();
for(var prop in bob){
    newBob[prop] = bob[prop];
}
```

Be aware that in both cases, bob loses his "inherited" methods and properties from the old prototype, although in the latter case only the non-enumerable ones (as stated in the comments). The enumerable ones will get copied and bound to the new object directly, possibly overriding inherited methods, so be aware of that, too.

Also worth reading: https://reinteractive.com/posts/235-es6-classes-and-javascript-prototypes

[edit] Example code with `Object.keys`:

```
newBob = new specialCust();
Object.keys(bob).forEach(function(prop){
    newBob[prop] = bob[prop];
});
```

Comment: Using *for..in*, you'll copy over enumerable inherited methods too. ;-) Might be better to use `Object.keys(bob).forEach(...)`.

Comment: Right. Of course. I will change the formulation. Also `for..of` would be possible instead of `Object.keys`, but I assume, that bob is not a collection.

Comment: @RobG Thanks but would you please write that as an example code because I am still not aware of Object.keys.

Comment: @Psi I did the same but it only iterated over the very first property and ignored the two others I had already in old bob. (I had three props in old bob but only the first was assigned as the first prop of newBob)

var newBob = new specialCustomer();
 Object.keys(bob).forEach(function(key) {
  newBob[bob] = bob[key];
 });

Comment: that depends on where the properties in the old bob came from. If they were part of the prototype, they would not be taken into account (that's what I said)

Comment: Why ’newBob[bob] = bob[key]’? you mean ’newBob[key] = bob[key]’. You want rhe property to be copied, don't you?